# Jquery get json data from data type dataString

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the  following jquery function which submits data to the  database :

```
  $('#book_client_form').submit(function (event) {
                    dataString = $("#book_client_form").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>operations/book_client",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('.job_card_id').val(data[0].id);
                            $(".info_box_reload").show('slow');
                            setInterval(function () {

                                $(".add_new_client_div").hide('slow');
                                $(".clients_table_div").show('slow');
                            }, 3000);

                        }

                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
```

Once the  data is supposed to returned the last insert id in json format which gives me the  following output :

```
[{"id":"17"}]
```

But when I try to pass it to a text field or alert it , I get an undefined output or passes empty. Please advise on how can I pass it to the  text input? I'm using datatype : datastring.

Comment: You probably get string response from server try JSON.parse to get js object from string.

Comment: Can you try with async:false under $.ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try parsing the JSON data?

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data[0].id); // you can see the id in the dev console
$('.job_card_id').val(data[0].id);
```

or you can set dataType : 'jsonp' to get a JavaScript object as response

> use dataType,  its case sensitive.